# List.subLisist(index1,index2) Not Grabbing Last Index

Tags: java, arrays, sublist

List.subLisist(index1,index2) Not Grabbing Last Index. It says index to index but, really it's index to index + 1 of the last value will get your output.

Output:

`["a:null", "b:b", "b:b", "b:null", "c:null", "d:null"]
 ["a:null"]`

Code:

```
list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("\"a:null\"");
    list.add("\"b:b\"");
    list.add("\"b:b\"");
    list.add("\"b:null\"");
    list.add("\"c:null\"");
    list.add("\"d:null\"");
    System.out.println(list);
     List<String> sub = list.subList(0, 1);
    System.out.println(sub);
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 2):

In Java, [`List.subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)):

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, **exclusive**.

Comment: which in english for inclusive to index